# Java Swing: How do you change colors of very cell in a JTable column based on text?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a basic JTable filled with "item number" and the corresponding "color" for that item, and I need to change the color of the cell that contains that name of the color to that actual color, regardless of whether it is selected or not.

This is the code to my JTable:

```
    String[] title = {"Item Number", "Color"};
    String[][] listOfValues = {{"1", "red"}, {"2", "blue"}, {"3", "green"}};

    JTable new_table = new JTable(listOfValues, title);
    JScrollPane table_pane = new JScrollPane(new_table);
    table_pane.setBounds(10, 10, 300, 230);
    frame.getContentPane().add(table_pane);
```

The layout is temporary. This is what the table looks like:

[image]

So, in this table, the cell containing "red" would be red, the cell containing "blue" would be blue and the cell containing "green" would be green. All other cells remain white like they are.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: 1) *"How do you change colors of very cell in a JTable coloumn based on text?"* Use a `TableCellRenderer` 2) `table_pane.setBounds(10, 10, 300, 230);` Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code permits to change the row's color

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.examen.navegacion;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;

/**
 *
 * @author wilso
 */
public class Fiea {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
        String[] title = {"Item Number", "Color"};
        String[][] listOfValues = {{"1", "red"}, {"2", "blue"}, {"3", "green"}};

        JTable new_table = new JTable(listOfValues, title);
        JScrollPane table_pane = new JScrollPane(new_table);
        table_pane.setBounds(10, 10, 300, 230);
        frame.getContentPane().add(table_pane);

        new_table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                final Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

                c.setBackground(getColor(value.toString()));
                return c;
            }
        });
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static Color getColor(String color) {
        switch (color) {
            case "red":
                return Color.RED;
            default:
                return Color.white;
        }

    }

}
```

Result  is the next

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked  :)  This is my first time using JTables, so will look up a guide on how to use it better and how DefaultTableCellRenderer works.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own TableCellRenderer and, in your case, look for all text cells, or look for the second column (you can use lot's of different creative approaches in a CellRenderer implementation to locate your target cells that you want to render in specific ways.)

Also, another alternative would be to leverage upon the html abilities of a JLabel, and then just do it when you build your data. This can work well too in simple cases, and means you don't have to implement your own renderer, not in a case like yours. You could use the JLabel's `<html>` abilities..

```
String colorString = "red";
String jLabelString = "<html><font color=" + colorString + ">" + colorString;
```

Like this sort of thing ...

```
String[][] listOfValues = {{"1",jLabelString}, {"2","<html><font color=blue>blue"},etc,etc};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I will give this a shot too  :)